# How to insert pH with chemmacros in LaTeX?

Tags: chemmacros

I see there is a way to insert `pH` with `chemmacros` in LaTeX. On the page 6 of [chemmacros](https://mirrors.cloud.tencent.com/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/chemmacros/chemmacros-manual.pdf)
[image]

But my code reminds me that `! Undefined control sequence. l.5 pH \ph`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemformula,chemmacros}
\begin{document}
pH \ph

\end{document}
```

Which cause this problem?

Comment: Unrelated to the question itself, but looks like you mixed up `1` with `l` in `l.5`. Probably you might want to try other monospace fonts so that you could easily distinguish between similarly looking glyphs. I recently fell in love with [JuliaMono](https://juliamono.netlify.app) since it is free, provides great Unicode support and helps to distinguish between chars easier.

Comment: @andselisk Thanks for your reply. These codes `! Undefined control sequence. l.5 pH \ph` I copied from texworks, in which `l` represent line so I did mix up `1` with `l`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commands in LaTeX are case sensitive. You should say `\pH` instead of `\ph`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemformula,chemmacros}
\begin{document}
    pH \pH
\end{document}
```

[image: output]